# PHP and Jquery's json

Tags: php, jquery, json, types

My html file:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: "id=1",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(msg){
                $('.result1').html(msg["name"]);
            }
        });  
    })
    </script>   

    <span class="result1"></span>
```

My php file:

```
    <?
    $a["name"] = 'john';
    echo json_encode($a);
    ?>
```

Why the name John doesn't appear in class result1? Why? Please help me, I am going insane.

**edit:** Is it possible to make bounty right now?

Comment: If you use the Firebug extension in Firefox, or developer tools in Chrome, you can see the request and response, and look at the data that is coming back from the server.

Comment: It comes {"name":"john"}, that means it's good, so what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dataType` parameter has a capital T. It works if you correct this.

Currently it is (by default) trying to guess the response format based on the mime-type, so probably defaulting to html - debugging in firebug you can see that the `msg` argument of the success callback is a string containing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Not to distract you from solving this problem.  But you may want to look into the .getJSON() function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/.  It's a little cleaner if you're just getting some data.

Also, take a look at the [JSON format](http://www.json.org/js.html), I think `data: "id=1"` should be `data: "{id:1}"`

And on the response side, keep in mind it's expecting multiple records so try: `msg[0].name;`, check out the [each() function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to process multiple records.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use:

```
 $('.result1').html(msg.name);
```

Comment: That won't make any difference.

Comment: In JavaScript, dot notation can often be substituted for array notation.  That's how something like document.forms["myForm"].elements["name"].value can be shortened to document.myForm.name.value (not that it's a good idea to do it).